# How does this way of accessing character in C-String work?

Tags: c, pointers, char, c-strings

[This question](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2017-set-2-question-53/) was asked in a recent exam where the candidate had to find the output for the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char * c = "GATECSIT2017";
    char *p = c;
    printf("%d", (int)strlen(c+2[p]-6[p]-1));
    return 0;
}
```

I started coding in C++ , so I wasn't an expert in C-Strings. After messing around with code, I understood how it worked, but one thing wasn't clear to me, which was this way of accessing a char from the char* string.

My question is, how `2[p]` gets the character at index 2?
Does it  resolve into `*(p+2)` or is there something else going on? Also, is there any documentation or any article that could explain this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is equal to `*(a + i)`.

Because of the [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of `+` the expression `*(a + i)` is equal to `*(i + a)`, which according to the first equality is equal to `i[a]`, i.e. switching place of the index and pointer/array.

So in your case the expression `2[p]` is equal to `*(2 + p)` which is equal to `*(p + 2)` which is equal to `p[2]`.

Using e.g. `2[p]` is only for (bad) obfuscation so please don't use it anywhere.

Comment: You made it very clear. How the index is resolved and the commutative property of the + operator lead to 2[p] being same as p[2].

Comment: Could you point to some resource that tells the behavior of [] ? Or any other resources related to this question?

Comment: @RishbhSharma [Here's a reference about the array subscript operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Subscript).